# Prove that $\dfrac{a+b}{c^2}+\dfrac{b+c}{a^2}+\dfrac{a+c}{b^2}\geq 2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)$

Tags: inequality

For $a, b$ and $c$ positive real number, prove following inequality $$\dfrac{a+b}{c^2}+\dfrac{b+c}{a^2}+\dfrac{a+c}{b^2}\geq 2\left(\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b}+\dfrac{1}{c}\right)$$

I did some attempts using AM-GM inequality such as.

$$\dfrac{a+b}{c^2}+\dfrac{b+c}{a^2}+\dfrac{c+a}{b^2}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{a+b}{c^2}\cdot\dfrac{b+c}{a^2}\cdot\dfrac{a+c}{b^2}}$$

But, my further manipulation made the expression getting more complex. i cannot make any simplification on it.

Comment: I have tried AM-GM and AM-HM with so many times combination but got nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the inequality is equivalent to the following nice form:

$$ ( a + b + c ) ( \frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2 } + \frac{1}{c^2} )  \geq 3 ( \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c}) $$

Recognize that this is Chebyshev (on oppositely arranged sequences).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove $a/c^2+c/a^2-1/a-1/c=(a+c)(1/a-1/c)^2$. From this, get an inequality; sum three versions of it viz. the cyclic symmetry.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much i will try. .

Comment: Thanks dude, it works 